# Google Places API usage

Tags: google-places-api

I have started using Google Places API. I intend to use it for my senior projects, which is an Android app.

I also have verified my identity to get extra free quotas.

But my question is - am I gonna be able to use the API always, or they will pause the access after 60 days?

p.s. as I read on their web-site that they pause trial after 60 days of using Google Cloud, I though may be the would do the same with an API.

Thank you

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is about license conditions of a 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed the Google Cloud team last month with the exact same question.  Here was the response I got:

> Hi Scott,
>
> You should enter your billing information in your Cloud Console.  Your
>   account is paused only if you start a trial and do not enter your
>   billing information.
>
> If you have any other questions, look through the Cloud Billing Help
>   Center. You can also contact the billing team through the Cloud
>   Console Billing Support Request form.
>
> Secondly, I did some more digging, and you can send an email to:
>   cloud-billing@google.com. That should put you in touch with the
>   billing team as well.